# Conditional Drop down list Text value in Yii

Tags: php, yii, html.dropdownlistfor, yii-booster, active-form

I have a drop down list but I the text value is dependent on another value from the same model.

What I want to happen is if the row from a model has a `client_type_id` value of `1` then the drop down text should be `company_name` else it will be the `first_name`. Kindly refer to the code below.

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownListRow($model , 'client_id', CHtml::listData(Client::model()->findAll(), 'id', '$data->client_type_id == 1 ? $data->company_name : $data->first_name')); ?>
```

Is it even possible to achieve it like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PHP 5.3+ and Yii 1.1.13+**

You can use an anonymous function:

```
echo $form->dropDownListRow($model , 'client_id', 
    CHtml::listData(Client::model()->findAll(), 'id', function($data){
        return $data->client_type_id == 1 ? $data->company_name : $data->first_name
    })
);
```

**Yii < 1.1.13 and/or PHP <5.3**

You can use the [`CActiveRecord::afterFind()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#afterFind-detail) method to initialize a variable say `$list_info` and use this as your field:

```
class MyClass extends CActiveRecord{
    public $list_info;
    ...

    public function afterFind(){
        $this->list_info=$this->client_type_id == 1 ? $this->company_name : $this->first_name
    }
}
```

The drop down list then becomes

```
$form->dropDownListRow($model , 'client_id', CHtml::listData(
    Client::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'list_info')
);
```

Reference: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listData-detail

Comment: Thanks but is there a way for versions 1.1.12 and below and with PHP 5.2?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've also modified your example to make it more consistent with the context.